# numpy: find the count of each unique element in an array

Tags: python, search, numpy

I have an array which has many repeating elements and I want to find the count and the value of the  non-zero element that repeats the most. I sort of have it working but I am not sure if this is correct way to do it in python.

Some test code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

l = list()
for i in np.unique(x):
    l.extend((np.count_nonzero(x[x==i]),))

maximum_times = np.max(l)
```

This tells me the number of times the maximum element has repeated but it does not tell me what that element is and perhaps using the for loop is not a good idea for this but I could not come up with any other pythonic solution.

Comment: Numpy version? In 1.9 you can pass in `return_counts=True` to `unique()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ashwini noted, you can use `return_counts=True` for this.

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

elements, repeats = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
index = repeats.argmax()
elem = elements[index]

print "Max elem is " + str(elem) + " with " + str(repeats[index]) + " repetitions."
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than my try. Thanks.